# How to send constant value along with api get request to node server

Tags: node.js, angular, api, get

I have a api service in which there is a method to fetch data from the mongo db through node server. But i want to send the value of `const userplant = localStorage.getItem("userplant");` along with the get request to the GET router in my node server so i can filter the data with a ***WHERE*** condition.

**API.SERVICE.TS**

```
getStorageLocationsList(){
    this.setHeader();
    const userplant = localStorage.getItem("userplant"); //I Want to send this to the GET router
    return this.http.get(this.localURL + 'storagelocation/view', {headers:this.appHeader});
  }
```

**ROUTER.JS**

```
router.get('/storagelocation/view', auth, function(req, res, next) {
    StorageLocation.find({plantId : "5dd262a61120910d94326cc1"}, function (err, events) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      res.json(events);
    });
  });
```

I want the value of `userplant` next to the `{plantId : "here"}`

P.S.: My get request is perfectly working , i just want to send the const value along with it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use queryParams to do that:

**API.SERVICE.TS**

```
getStorageLocationsList(){
    this.setHeader();
    const userplant = localStorage.getItem("userplant"); //I Want to send this to the GET router
    return this.http.get(this.localURL + 'storagelocation/view' + '?userplant=' + userplant , {headers:this.appHeader});
  }
```

**ROUTER.JS**

```
router.get('/storagelocation/view', auth, function(req, res, next) {
    let userplant = req.query.userplant;
    // you can use it now
    StorageLocation.find({plantId : "5dd262a61120910d94326cc1"}, function (err, events) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      res.json(events);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the following changes in Angular, you can pass headers and parameters like this:

```
const httpOptions = {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        params: {userplant:userplant}
    };
getStorageLocationsList(){
    this.setHeader();
    const userplant = localStorage.getItem("userplant"); 
    return this.http.get(this.localURL + 'storagelocation/view',httpOptions);
  }
```

Make the following change in Node Js,you have to use body parser.

```
router.get('/storagelocation/view', auth, function(req, res, next) {
    var plantId=req.body.plantId;
    StorageLocation.find({plantId : plantId}, function (err, events) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      res.json(events);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

In query params you can send.

```
getStorageLocationsList(){
    this.setHeader();
    const userplant = localStorage.getItem("userplant"); //I Want to send this to the GET router
    const params = new HttpParams().set('userplant ',userplant);
    return this.http.get(this.localURL + 'storagelocation/view', {headers:this.appHeader, params: params});
}
```